# Create a class library that will work on all windows platforms

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, portable-class-library, preprocessor-directive

I have a **Class Library Project** that I would like to make use of on the Windows Phone and Silverlight Apps (Windows 8.1). Effectively turn it into a **Class Libary (Portable)**.

My Class Library has a `Window` base class (inherits from `System.Windows.Window`), however this is not available in **portable** class libraries.

To make this simple:

1) Is it possible to create a universal class library that will allow me to use it on the windows desktop, as well as windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.1?

2) How can I add a class that inherits from `System.Windows.Window` in a **portable class library**? Do I need to use pre-processor directives? How would I go about referencing `System.Windows`?

Am I going about this in the right way? Is there a better solution?

Comment: you can't share UI components.

Comment: If you are willing to sacrifice the .NET platform, you might consider [Xamarin.Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms), which allows you to define most of the UI in a portable class library. *Xamarin.Forms* currently targets Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 Silverlight, but support for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 (non-Silverlight) is [on its way](http://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin.forms-for-windows-store-preview-and-xamarin-for-oss/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A PCL only allows a specific subset of the .NET framework. Depending on your configuration, this is more or less of the entire framework.

What you can't do, in any way, is including assemblies and types that are not compatible with the PCL, like in this case `System.Windows.Window`.

So the answer is: you can't do that. Create a new assembly for the parts that are UI based.

Comment: @Mike need more help?